# Run coverlet and reportgenerator in a macOS DevOps Pipeline

Tags: yaml, code-coverage, azure-pipelines, reportgenerator, coverlet

I have a C# project written in dotnet core 2.1 which I'm trying to set up an Azure Pipeline for so that I can get code coverage when running on a macOS agent (I can change to other agents, but ideally the pipeline would be system agnostic). So far I have been trying to get [coverlet](https://github.com/tonerdo/coverlet) and [reportgenerator](https://github.com/danielpalme/ReportGenerator) to work together, but I keep running into problems, such as `Could not find data collector 'XPlat Code Coverage'`.

What I would like to happen is the code coverage is determined (which coverlet seems to be doing) and a code coverage report generated and displayed in Azure pipelines in some manner.

This is the pipeline I have so far:

```
pool:
  vmImage: macOS-latest

variables:
  solution: 'src/MySolution.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Debug'

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreInstaller@1
  displayName: 'Use .NET Core sdk 2.2.103'
  inputs:
    version: 2.2.103

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Restore NuGet packages for $(solution)'
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: '$(solution)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Build $(solution)'
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '$(solution)'
    arguments: '-c $(buildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  continueOnError: true
  inputs:
    command: custom
    custom: tool
    arguments: install -g coverlet.console
  displayName: Install Coverlet tool. This task will continue on error.

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Run tests for $(solution) collecting code coverage result'
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: 'src/MySolution.SomeProject.Tests/*.csproj'
    arguments: -c $(buildConfiguration) --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage"

- script: coverlet src/MySolution.SomeProject.Tests/bin/$(buildConfiguration)/netcoreapp2.1/MySolution.SomeProject.Tests.dll --target "dotnet" --targetargs "test src/MySolution.SomeProject.Tests --no-build"
  displayName: Run Coverlet to get code coverage.

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  continueOnError: true
  inputs:
    command: custom
    custom: tool
    arguments: install -g dotnet-reportgenerator-globaltool
  displayName: Install ReportGenerator tool

# This outputs Analyzing 0 classes, and an index.htm file is created, but not sure how to access it
- script: reportgenerator -reports:$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/coverage.json -targetdir:$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/coverlet/reports -reporttypes:HtmlInline_AzurePipelines
  displayName: 'Create reports.'

# Not sure what this should be
- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
  displayName: 'Publish code coverage'
  inputs:
    codeCoverageTool: Cobertura
    summaryFileLocation: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/coverlet/reports/Cobertura.xml
```

Comment: In windows/ubuntu agents it works?

Comment: No, I only put macOS as that was what we have setup as our self-hosted agent. I've got it working now, so will post what I found as an answer and hopefully benefit others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I got it working. I had some how missed that you can specify the format that `coverlet` uses. By default it outputs `coverage.json`, but by giving the format as `cobertura` it outputs `coverage.cobertura.xml`. So this yaml script works:

```
pool:
  vmImage: macOS-latest

variables:
  solution: 'src/MySolution.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Debug'

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreInstaller@1
  displayName: 'Use .NET Core sdk 2.2.103'
  inputs:
    version: 2.2.103

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Restore NuGet packages for $(solution)'
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: '$(solution)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Build $(solution)'
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '$(solution)'
    arguments: '-c $(buildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Run tests for $(solution) collecting code coverage result'
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: 'src/MySolution.SomeProject.Tests/*.csproj'
    arguments: -c $(buildConfiguration)

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  continueOnError: true
  inputs:
    command: custom
    custom: tool
    arguments: install -g coverlet.console
  displayName: Install Coverlet tool. This task will continue on error.

- script: coverlet src/MySolution.SomeProject.Tests/bin/$(buildConfiguration)/netcoreapp2.1/MySolution.SomeProject.Tests.dll --target "dotnet" --targetargs "test src/MySolution.SomeProject.Tests --no-build" --format cobertura
  displayName: Run Coverlet to get code coverage.

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  continueOnError: true
  inputs:
    command: custom
    custom: tool
    arguments: install -g dotnet-reportgenerator-globaltool
  displayName: Install ReportGenerator tool

- script: reportgenerator -reports:$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/coverage.cobertura.xml -targetdir:$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/coverlet/reports -reporttypes:HtmlInline_AzurePipelines
  displayName: 'Create reports.'

- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
  displayName: 'Publish code coverage'
  inputs:
    codeCoverageTool: Cobertura
    summaryFileLocation: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/coverage.cobertura.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add the following NuGet PackageReference to your project .csproj file

```
<PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="1.1.0">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
```

And you can follow [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/dotnet-core?view=azure-devops) to set up your pipeline

Comment: The project should not need to depend on coverlet as it is only being used by the build pipeline.